# How to upload file from a linux server to google cloud storage using airflow composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to transfer a local file from linux server to google cloud storage using Airflow but when I run the dag, the file is being uploaded.

**Code**

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.local_to_gcs import LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator

@dag(schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args)
def upload_file_to_gcs_dag():
    upload_file = LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator(
        task_id="upload_file_to_gcs_dag",
        src='/home/james/test_data.sql.gz',
        dst='dags/data/test_data.sql.gz',
        bucket= BUCKET_NAME
    )
    upload_file 
    
dag = upload_file_to_gcs_dag()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using Cloud Composer or Airflow is running on your linux server?

Comment: It will also help if you will share the use case and the logs.